# Determine the duration of an audio file without third party components

Tags: c#, .net, audio

**Description:**

I try to determine the duration of an audio file, for example the duration of a song in seconds. I found a lot of articles about that topic but I did not find a solution that is not using a) a third party or b) an old Microsoft library that is already dead. Not finding such a solution does not mean there isn't a solution, it just means I did not dig deep enough or the right person didn't encounter such a question, yet. So I hope I will find somebody who can help me with this problem or refer me to someone/something who/that can.

Comment: I've removed thanks and hello from your post. For more info refer [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a wave file you just need to open it up, parse the header and within it you'll find the length of the audio data. There are a lot of questions on SO dealing with the format.

Basically you need the Subchunk2Size which is in bytes divided by NumChannels divided by the number byte per sample (BitsPerSample/8). That will give you the length in samples. If you need the time in seconds divide that by the sample rate.

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! I just knew about the 128 byte id3v1 meta data at the end of an audio file but not about these data at the beginning. I work with both .wav and .mp3, do you know about a similar chart for .mp3 ? Anyways thanks a lot !